# Do files on your server influence website speed

Tags: apache, webserver

If you have a webserver for your website, does it make a difference if there are a lot of other files on the server, even if they aren't used?

### Example

An average webserver has a SSD with 500 GB of space. It's hosting a single website, but has a ton of other websites which are inactive. Though that single website is only 1GB in size, the hard drive is full for 50%. Will that influence site speed?

And does SSD vs HDD make a difference in that, apart from the speed difference between the two types.

Edit: I've read somewhere that the amount of files in your server influences it's speed, and it sounds logical due to Andrei's answer, concerning the having to search through more files. I've had a discussion about it with someone however, and he firmly states that it makes no difference.

Comment: does having extra forks/spoons in your cutlery drawer affect how fast you eat supper?

Comment: yes it does if you need to find one uniquely named fork and not just any fork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having other/unused files always has an impact on the performance, but the question is - how big it is. Usually not much and you will not notice it at all.

But think about how files are read from disk. First, you need to locate the file record in the file allocation table (FAT). Search in the table is similar to search in a tree-like data structure, as we have to deal with folders that contain other folders etc.

The more files you have, the bigger the FAT gets. And the search becomes slower, correspondingly.

All in all, with memory caching and other tricks, this is not an issue.

You will notice the impact when you have thousands of files in one folder. That's why picture-related services that host big amount of images usually store them in a folder structure that holds only limited amount of files per folder. For example, a file named '12345678.jpg' would be stored in '/1/2/3/4/5/12345678.jpg' path as well as other files whose names are '12345000'...'12345999'. Thus only 1000 files would be saved per folder.